# how to uniquely identify users in websocket?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am confused on how to give each new person that connects to the websocket a unique identification that can only affect his own information on the server. the information on the websocket is broadcast-ed so everyone receives the information from the server. I am using socket io for this.

Comment: Can you show us your server-sided code?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really enough information to provided a answer tailored to your needs, however here is a common method of sharing session data with sockets using an express.js memory store.

```
var sio = require('socket.io'),
parseCookies = require('connect').utils.parseSignedCookies

// authorization for sockets
io.set('authorization', function (hsData, accept) {
    //get the handshake data for the socket
  if(hsData.headers.cookie) {
    //parse the cookies from the handshake data
    var cookies = parseCookies(cookie.parse(hsData.headers.cookie), "session secret"),
    sid = cookies["session path"];
    //load your session store and find the user
    sessionStore.load(sid, function(err, session) {
      hsData.user = session.user;
      return accept(null, true);
    });
  } else {
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  }
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    //now the socket will have user data
  var user = socket.handshake.user,
 });
```

Take a look at [Baloons.IO](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO) to look at some great source code where sessions and socket.io live in harmony using a redis store.

Hope this helps!